# Permanent Notification From Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to send permanent notification from firebase cloud functions? User can't dismiss that notification?

Comment: If an app does something like this, regardless of any platform, I as a user would immediately uninstall that app.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you cannot, but Android you could setup a local notification using remote config.

#### iOS Remote Notifications

While you could send the same notification over and over again, control of the notifications is at the OS level of the client device.  iOS would never let you create a local or remote notification that cannot be dismissed because it would be a poor user experience.  In addition, I think you would find that your users would not be happy about it as well.

An alternative, would be to create a custom UI Header in your app that includes a label. You could then use Firebase Remote Config to set a value for that label, that way you can deliver the same message to all users of your app.

#### Android Push Notifications

In Android, it looks like you can have permanent notifications.  However, it looks like this is controlled at the client level.  So I still recommend the **remote config** option here as well.  Set the value of the remote config, and then generate a local notification and set the notification to not clear.

`notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;`

Perhaps, a key/value pair could be sent from your Firebase Cloud Message call, but you will run into other issues as well.  When should the function be called?  Will you generate a new notification for every new user added to Firebase?  This could become more expensive versus the remote config route.

#### Google Chrome Notifications

The **remote config** option should scale to this as well.  A quick Google search didn't show anything that would suggest you can do a permanent notification like Android.  And even if you could then your solution wouldn't work in Safari and other browsers.

Comment: there is no way to add any condition in javascript code of cloud function to make that notification permanent.???

Comment: No, again it involves the specific Operating System.  We'll keep using iOS as an example.  Apple controls displaying the notification.  You have the options to add buttons so it will perform extra features, but if there are no buttons Apple will eventually dismiss the notification since they are controlling the UI for all notifications.  Even if you found a way around that they would most likely reject your app from the App Store for breaking their notification standards.  It's just something you do not have control over because a notification is meant to be temporary.

Comment: then how i m getting notifications  on my phone from some apps or  from google chrome  on web which i cant dismiss??

Comment: Is your phone iOS or Android?  What OS is Google Chrome running on?